# What fields deploy with NamedCredential?

Tags: apex, integration, callout, namedcredentials

I have a callout where we use a `Named Credential` and it looks something like the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>
        {
            'Authorization' => 'Basic {!$Credential.AuthorizationHeaderValue}'
        };
    }
    public SomeType makeCallout(/*parameters*/)
    {
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            this,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[]{
                'callout:My_Credential'
                // other parameters
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Notice I am using an endpoint of `callout:My_Credential` and using `$Credential.AuthorizationHeaderValue` in my `Authorization` header.

This callout worked great in the development sandbox. When we deployed it to UAT along with the `Named Credential`, however, it didn't work. We were getting a 401 response. I changed the header to hard code the token and the callout worked, so it looked like a password issue. I edited the `Named Credential` record to reset the password to exactly what it was in the development environment, and the problem was resolved.

Do `Named Credential` records deploy without `Password` being populated? Or does the `$Credential.AuthorizationHeaderValue` just not get carried through? Is it possible to deploy a credential with either of these values intact?

Comment: A named credential metadata retrieve doesn't include the password, but one can be included in the metadata when it's deployed to the target org.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating Named Credential with password](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101366/migrating-named-credential-with-password)

Comment: I'm not asking about ANT (using Change Sets). Still, I guess the answer is just "no".

Comment: Yes. Sounds like it needs to be a post-deployment step for your process.

Comment: Well feel free to add as an answer before we close.

Comment: The [Spring 15](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_packaging_named_credentials.htm) release notes (when Named Credential became packageable and change-set-able) specify that the Credential must be re-authorized after installation from a package. In my experience, the same thing is true for change set deployments, but I've never seen it documented explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A retrieve of Named Credential metadata does not include the sensitive field data, including `password`.

That said, `password` data can be included in metadata during the deployment and the password will be set in the target org.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NamedCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <endpoint>https://your.endpoint.url</endpoint>
    <label>endpoint_name</label>
    <principalType>NamedUser</principalType>
    <protocol>Password</protocol>
    <password>actual_password</password>
    <username>user@example.com</username>
</NamedCredential>
```